# Remote method call with shared objects in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, web-services

I need to do a conceptually simple thing:

Call a remote method from a WPF application to the server. But I need to share the model types with both sides.. I mean, I need to send a Person object as parameter from the client and also receive objects of the same type.

What's the best way? Is it to use WCF? Is there a better way?
Do you have a code snippet or simple example for that?

I appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard advice these days is to use WCF for that.  It has the flexibility to make the connection using any number of technologies (TCP/IP, SOAP, REST, ...) and can use declarative configuration which is all the rage.

Depending on your environment and the technology the server is developed in you might also want to look at .NET Remoting or an ASP.NET web service.